# How to link a class with a specific table of the data base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So i'm trying to link a class to a specific table of the data base, so far i do have my class and i think that i have the table as well, but how do i link them?

In my program i have a class client, and i want every client to have a link to a table with configurations.

This is the migration.

Thanks

```
class ClientsConfigSettings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table "clients_config" do |t|
      t.boolean "when_credential_blocked", default: true
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `references`:

```
class ClientsConfigSettings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table "clients_config" do |t|
      t.references :client
      t.boolean "when_credential_blocked", default: true
    end
  end
end
```

This will add `client_id` to the new table. So these two tables can be joined using this column.

Comment: Don't forget to add the 'has_one :clients_config' or 'has_many :clients_configs' on the Client model.

Comment: @RobNice Thanks! When i try to create an instance of ´clients_config´ it throws an error that says that the instance is null. How can i do to create an instance of clients_config with all the variables that are included in the db set?  Thanks for helping me

Comment: In what environment are you trying to create the client_config? I recommend playing around in the Rails Console (run the 'rails c' command in the terminal in your project's root folder) and create your instances there. So, create a new Client, then on your Client instance do a client.clients_config = ClientsConfig.new ().

You'll probably get some validation errors, but you'll at least be able to see what's missing.